# How do I let a user tweet an image?

Tags: javascript, python, twitter

We have a twitter button set up where users click on it and a popup opens up to let the user tweet from their own account. How can we include an image with that tweet? (With facebook we've been able to do it).

```
<div>

   <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
      data-url="http://www.mysite.com"
      data-text="sharing this with you...."
      data-count="none">Tweet</a>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
       window.location = "http://www.mysite.com"

    });

</script>
```

Comment: did you check out the twitter api. dev.twitter.com

Comment: "of course i did" ...and?

Comment: Take a look at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media.

Comment: @doorknob: use your best guess: A. I found the info I needed and decided not to post on S.O. or B. I did not find the info I needed and decided to ask on S.O.

Comment: Then include that in your question. [ask]

Comment: where do you think I got the code I posted? from the docs.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to use the API directly (not just their widget). Details on how to post with a media item can be found at the [status/update_with_media](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media) docs.

If you're looking for a kind of rendering a 'preview' of a link (what Facebook allows through Open Graph), then checkout the [Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards) documentation.

Comment: unless I'm wrong, the first method will essentially make the tweet come from our account, not our user's account. The second method needs a pre-authorization from twitter to use. In my experience twitter support is sloooowwwww.

Comment: @Mr.Gaga The fist method would allow you to post from any account that has granted your app OAuth Post access (just like any Twitter app). 

Yes, the second method would require approval, but if that's what you're after (rendering a preview of a link) that's the only way. If you just want to post media, use the first method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media/uploading-media